# How often do I need to save the context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In a repository, I am doing these two consecutive tasks:

```
// Update vendorOrder
vendorOrder.VendorOrderStatus = VendorOrderStatus.Completed;
vendorOrderRepository.UpdateVendorOrder(vendorOrder);
vendorOrderRepository.Save();
// Update order
order.OrderStatus = OrderStatus.Completed;
orderRepository.UpdateOrder(order);
orderRepository.Save();
```

Both `vendorOrderRepository` and `orderRepositoryrepositorty` have their own `Save()` method:

```
public void Save()
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

- Will calling `Save()` inside each repository save only changes to the 
  context there, or will it save each and every change made to context
  in any other repositories up to that point?
- In my example, is it redundant to call `Save()` twice? Will it work if I just call `Save()` at the very end?

(I could just try myself and see what works, but I want to have a definite answer based on how MVC works if possible, in case there are exceptions. It's probably basic understanding of MVC, but I skipped that part...)

### Edit 1

vendorOrderRepository begins with:

```
public class VendorOrderRepository : IVendorOrderRepository, IDisposable
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private IOrderRepository orderRepository;
    public VendorOrderRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        orderRepository = new OrderRepository(context);
    }
```

orderRepository begins with:

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository, IDisposable
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private IVendorOrderRepository vendorOrderRepository;
    public OrderRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        vendorOrderRepository = new VendorOrderRepository(context);
    }
```

Comment: This is asking about the behavior of Entity Framework, not MVC.

Comment: Is `context` a shared instance between the repositories or does each repo have its own?

Comment: I think it would awkward to call Save on one repo and have it actually save them all. At best it would cause developer misunderstanding. I hope each repo has its own context.

Comment: `UnitOfWork` will save you. one operation is a kind of `transaction`, if one of them fail, others should fail too. so you cannot `save` one by one, no matter in that project. BTW, Repository Pattern is an anti-pattern, avoid to use it.

Comment: Try UoW pattern, see: [Creating the Unit of Work (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#creating-the-unit-of-work-class)

Comment: The Entity Framework `DbContext` is ALREADY using the Unit of Work pattern. You do NOT need to try and build a UoW framework around it. You will just end up creating pain and trouble for yourself. Unit of Work, is an Entity Framework Anti-Pattern.

Comment: @BradleyUffner no, it's just data access layer, but for business logic layer, we need another wrapper.

Comment: You will need to show us how you are creating the context and setting it in the repo's otherwise we are just guessing

Comment: "I could just try myself and see what works" Sure! This has nothing to do with MVC. It's only about how you happen to implement the repository pattern of which we don't see all relevant details. So at this moment you're the only one who can give the "definite answer"

Comment: On a related note: never skip the basics.

Comment: @CSmith - I just added the context creation code. Can you comment on that?

Comment: @TylerH - as I keep learning, the basics keep changing...

Comment: @Alfred The basics may expand a bit over time, but just because we have discovered stuff beyond calculus today does not mean you can skip basic arithmetic and jump straight to algebra or geometry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How often do I need to save the context?

As often as it makes sense to do so. In general, you will want to only call SaveChanges once, unless dealing with large sets in which case it will make sense to use transactions and save in batches.

> Will calling Save() inside each repository save only changes to the context there, or will it save each and every change made to context in any other repositories up to that point?

"the context there" is kind of vague. Calling SaveChanges will save *all* changes made inside of the context. So, if both `vendorOrderRepository` and `orderRepository` share the same context, then calling it once will save every change made.

> In my example, is it redundant to call Save() twice? Will it work if I just call Save() at the very end?

If they use the same context, then yes. If different, then it is not redundant.

---

In a broader sense, the way that SaveChanges works is that it will save the entities stored in the change tracker (See [ChangeTracker Class <sup>MDN</sup>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker) for expanded details). The change tracker (accessible through `context.ChangeTracker`), among other things, holds a set of entities that it tracks. These will be the entities which are updated during SaveChanges, and technically these entities are referred to as being "attached".

You can see the list of entities attached by type by iterating `context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>()` where `T` is your type.

Comment: Very constructive answer and useful tip with  `context.ChangeTracker`. As a best practice, do you recommend saving in 2 steps `orderRepository.UpdateOrder(order); orderRepository.Save();` or 1 step by including Save() inside `orderRepository.UpdateOrder(order);`?

Comment: If possible, only one round trip (save) should be used. However, as you open two difference contexts, in your case it must be called for both unless you are injecting one into the other.